# DataContractSerializer stuck on WriteObject

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I have objects (woah!) which can serialise themselves using a `Serialise` method.
I've tried multiple serialise methods, but all have been stuck on the `serialize.WriteObject` method.

This is what my latest try looks like:

```
public string Serialise()
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(this.GetType());
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, this);
    ms.Position = 0;

    string serializedContent;
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
    {
        serializedContent = sr.ReadToEnd();   
    }
    return serializedContent;
}
```

I used to do this with a `XmlSerializer` and those didn't give me any trouble.
I'm pretty sure I made my properties a `DataMember` and set up de `DataContract` of the class.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it the way I want to use this Serialisation? Is it because I want to serialise inside the class with the DataContract? I'm baffled..

------EDIT---------

Ugh.. I figured out what the problem was... My BaseObject had no DataContract and no DataMembers on their properties (although i would not want any of those properties in my xml). So apparently making only a DataContract for the extended class is not enough to serialise it.

Comment: Do you really have this method in any object you want to serialize? Looks like a prime candidate for an extension method on object to me.

Comment: What do you mean "stuck" on?

Comment: Well, right now it covers only 2 classes so the effects are not that impactful, but it is probably worth to do so when this amount grows. Also this DataContractSerialisation is part of a test to see if I can replace the XmlSerialisation that is already in place.

Comment: @CathalMF Well when it tries to execute this line it just sticks to this endlessly. It doesn't get to the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can try out this one

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            try
            {
                string xml = string.Empty;
                var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(this.GetType());

                using (var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.Default))
                {
                    xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    dcs.WriteObject(xmlTextWriter, this);
                    xmlTextWriter.Flush();
                    var item = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
                    item.Flush();
                    xml = new UTF8Encoding().GetString(item.ToArray());
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                ms.Close();
            }
        }

        return xml;
```

Comment: This gives me the same results. So I suspect the problem is not really in the way the serialisation is coded. It keeps sticking to the WriteObject line.

Comment: how does your object "this" look like -- posting code would probably help nail down the problem...

Comment: Ugh.. I figured out what the problem was... My BaseObject had no DataContract and no DataMembers on their properties (although i would not want any of those properties in my xml). So apparently making only a DataContract for the extended class is not enough to serialise it. The moment I made this DataContract for the BaseObject, it worked...

Comment: hehehe --- always the obvious things got overseen :)

Comment: I'm fairly new to these DataContracts, still figuring out what the ins and outs are of these things. Thanks for the help though.